# configure keeps finding the wrong GLib

Tags: automake

My cygwin has glib1.2 and glib2.0 installed. My configure.in contains the following lines:

```
AM_PATH_GLIB_2_0(,
[
        AC_DEFINE(HAVE_GLIB)
        LIBS="$LIBS $GLIB_LIBS"
        CFLAGS="$CFLAGS $GLIB_CFLAGS"
], [
        AC_MSG_ERROR([No glib. Bad.  Get it at:  http://www.gtk.org/. ])
])
```

Unfortunately, the GLIB_CONFIG macro contains:

```
echo -I${prefix}/include/glib-1.2
```

So whenever I do a ./configure, my makefile returns to this:

```
gcc  -g -O2 -I/usr/include/glib-1.2
```

...and then all the code calling 2.x complains. I can fix this with some manual edits to the resulting makefile:

```
GLIB_CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
GLIB_CONFIG = /usr/bin/glib-config
GLIB_LIBS = -L/usr/lib -lglib-2.0
```

... but avoiding that is why you use autoconf in the first place. Questions:

1. is there another GLIB_CONFIG that should exist somewhere? should 2.0 have changed this one on install? I poked about in /usr/bin, and that's the only gl* in there.
2. I'm not sure I understand where in the configure process GLIB_CONFIG being called

Answer (score 1):

I personally would use `pkg-config` in `configure.ac` by calling the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro:

```
m4_pattern_forbid([PKG_CHECK_MODULES])dnl
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GLIB20], [glib-2.0], [], [dnl
  AC_MSG_ERROR([
   +===================================================+
   | Could not find the required glib-2.0 dev package. |
   | Install the glib2-devel or libglib2-dev package   |
   | or from http://www.gtk.org/ directly.             |
   +===================================================+
])
])
```

The `m4_pattern_forbid` prevents `autoreconf` from succeeding without the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro being defined, and you can adapt the error message to your heart's content.

The `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro works for a huge number of libraries, and it clearly defines which API you are looking for. Just check for `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/*.pc` files (the exact location for your system might vary).

In your `Makefile.am` or `Makefile-files` file, you can then add the GLIB20 flags like

```
bin_PROGRAMS  = foo
foo_SOURCES   = foo-main.c
foo_CPPFLAGS  = $(top_srcdir)/include
foo_LDADD     = $(top_builddir)/libfoo.la

foo_CPPFLAGS += $(GLIB20_CFLAGS)
foo_LDADD    += $(GLIB20_LIBS)
```